# React page does not rerender on url query change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, components, rerender

I'm trying to create a react page having different content based on the query in the url. ex: `things?type=0` and `things?type=1` resulting in different filtered content.

The problem is, React isn't triggering a rerender of my page when switching to these pages. I need to manually refresh the page to get the desired result.

I tried to use the build in lifecycle features but non of them triggers the page to refresh. It tried to do my fetch in the `componentWillReceiveProps` method with then I have to click twice on the link to get my filtered content (which is better than no page refresh but not user friendly).

I use this [reference](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html).

Answer (score -1):

You will probably want to use https://github.com/reactjs/react-router or some similar library for routes.

If you want to go on your own you have to listen to browser history changes. You could do it like this for example:

```
componentDidMount: function () {
  var component = this;

  window.onpopstate = function() {
    console.log(window.history.state);
    component.setState({
      query: window.location.search
    });
  };
};
```

I am not sure if this is the good way to go, but it should work at least.